# Background color for TabControl?

Tags: tabcontrol, geckofx

I'm working on a browser that's running on Geckofx, and well I can't find a way to change the color of the TabControl
I don't want to change the tab page, I want to change the container.

Here's what I mean:

This is what i'm trying to do:

[image]

And this is where i'm at:

[image]

I'm already using this for the tabs

```
    private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            TabPage CurrentTab = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
            Rectangle ItemRect = tabControl.GetTabRect(e.Index);
            SolidBrush FillBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            SolidBrush FBG = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush TextBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(e.State & DrawItemState.Selected))
            {
                FillBrush.Color = Color.Black;
                TextBrush.Color = Color.Green;
                ItemRect.Inflate(0, 0);
            }

            if (tabControl.Alignment == TabAlignment.Left || tabControl.Alignment == TabAlignment.Right)
            {
                float RotateAngle = 90;
                if (tabControl.Alignment == TabAlignment.Left)
                    RotateAngle = 270;
                PointF cp = new PointF(ItemRect.Left + (ItemRect.Width / 3), ItemRect.Top + (ItemRect.Height / 5));
                e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(cp.X, cp.Y);
                e.Graphics.RotateTransform(RotateAngle);
                ItemRect = new Rectangle(-(ItemRect.Height / 3), -(ItemRect.Width / 3), ItemRect.Height, ItemRect.Width);
            }
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(FillBrush, ItemRect);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(CurrentTab.Text, e.Font, TextBrush, (RectangleF)ItemRect, sf);
            e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
            FillBrush.Dispose();
            TextBrush.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I just have no idea how to change the color of the TabControl

I've looked over online everywhere and the examples either made 0 sense whatsoever or did not work.

I know it's possible from the example i've seen

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

TabControl have the propertie BackColor, from Control. Maybe if nothing work, try to set the DefaultBackColor to the color you need for your TabControl?
Look at this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor.aspx